# SF2 app crash app_dev works

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a project under Symfony2.
The project is actually online hosted by OVH. On this server everything is fine.
But, we are changing host right now. I am trying to configure new host.

I setup everything (SF2 works, mysql, apache too). When i launch web/app.php, the page stick blank, et I got these errors (on /var/log/apache2/error.log)

```
[Thu Jan 24 15:35:24 2013] [error] [client 31.39.43.247] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/carpediese/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 417
[Thu Jan 24 15:35:24 2013] [error] [client 31.39.43.247] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/homez.577/carpedief/app/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /var/www/carpediese/app/cache/prod/classes.php:9762\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/carpediese/app/cache/prod/classes.php(9691): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /var/www/carpediese/app/cache/prod/classes.php(9587): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2 /var/www/carpediese/app/cache/prod/classes.php(9831): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractHandler->handleBatch(Array)\n#3 /var/www/carpediese/app/ache/prod/classes.php(10113): Monolog\\Handler\\FingersCrossedHandler->handle(Array)\n#4 /var/www/carpediese/app/cache/prod/classes.php(10229): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(500, 'InvalidArgument...', Array)\n#5 /var/www/carpediese/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php(55): Monolog\\Logger->crit('InvalidArgument...')\n#6 [internal function]: Symfony\\Component\\HttpKer in /var/www/carpediese/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 9762
```

I really dont know what is the error. Which files creates the errors ? All the files mentionned in the log seems to be cache files...
I dont know what /homez.577 is ...

app_dev works really fine, either on OVH server than the new.

Do you got any ideas ?

Edit

I did the chmods.
Now i got no more errors on apache2 logs.
But (because there is always a but), when i load app.php, the page still stay blank.
I try to clean the cache with the command u give me, here is tthe answer.

Edit²

So i find a solution. I still cant clean the cache with the command, but i did a rm -Rf app/cache

Its working really nice. Thanky you dude!

Comment: Give us your solution please, can help other people :)

Comment: I did rm -Rf app/cache on my command line

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be the right of your folder.

Try : (your have to be located in the root of your project)

```
chmod -R 777 app/cache

chmod -R 777 app/logs
```

If it still doesn't work add :

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: I did the chmods. Now I got some really strange errors.
When I load app.php, the page still stay blank. But, there is no more errors in apache logs.
I do php app/console cache:clear, here is the resons ...

Comment: What is the version of your symfony ?

Answer (score 3):

Just for the next guy, to clear your production cache use the following:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```